# Dereference pointer to array of long from list iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, list, pointers

How do I correctly dereference pointers to arrays of `long`.
In the function `main` my code seems to print the addresses instead of the long values.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

bool
is_prime (long i)
{
    // fix wrong return values for 0 and 1
    if (i <= 1)
        return false;

    const long j = (long) std::sqrt(i);

    for (long k=2; k<j+1; ++k) {
        if (i % k == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

std::list<long(*)[2]>
goldbach (long number)
{
    std::list<long(*)[2]> sums;
    std::list<long(*)[2]>::iterator it;

    if (number < 4)  // Exclude too small integers.
        return sums;

    if (number % 2)  // Exclude uneven numbers.
        return sums;

    it = sums.begin();

    for (long candidate=2; candidate < number; ++candidate)
    {
        if (is_prime(candidate))
        {
            if (is_prime(number - candidate))
            {
                long sum[2];
                sum[0] = candidate;
                sum[1] = number - candidate;
                std::cout << sum[0] << " + " << sum[1] << "\n";
                sums.insert(it, &sum);
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }

    return sums;
}

int
main ()
{
    std::list<long(*)[2]> sums;
    std::list<long(*)[2]>::iterator it;

    for(long i = 4; i < 100; i+=2)
    {
        std::cout << "### " << i << " ###" << "\n";
        sums = goldbach(i);

        for (it = sums.begin(); it != sums.end(); ++it)
        {
            long num1 = *((*it)[0]);
            long num2 = *((*it)[1]);
            std::cout << num1  << " + "  << num2 << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `sums.insert(it, &sum);` stores a pointer to a variable local to the loop - it becomes dangling after the iteration ends

Comment: A list of pointers to arrays? Are you sure this unholy data structure is really necessary?

Comment: Let C++ be C++. Not C.

Comment: Thanks to all. I'll rethink my approach.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Maybe `std::list<long(*)[2]> sums;` -- Maybe `std::list<std::pair<long,long>> sums`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: What is a `std::list`? The only flat data structure in C++ is `std::vector` :-)

Comment: To add to that, consider turning `sums` into a simple struct or tuple, which you can return by value. There's really no need to use pointers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I realized that arrays within lists are a bad idea in C++.
I changed my code to the following, which works:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

bool
is_prime (long i)
{
    // fix wrong return values for 0 and 1
    if (i <= 1)
        return false;

    const long j = (long) std::sqrt(i);

    for (long k=2; k<j+1; ++k) {
        if (i % k == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

std::list<std::pair<long, long>>
goldbach (long number)
{
    std::list<std::pair<long, long>> sums;
    std::list<std::pair<long, long>>::iterator it;

    if (number < 4)  // Exclude too small integers.
        return sums;

    if (number % 2)  // Exclude uneven numbers.
        return sums;

    it = sums.begin();
    long complement;

    for (long candidate=2; candidate < number; ++candidate)
    {
        if (is_prime(candidate))
        {
            complement = number - candidate;

            if (is_prime(complement))
            {
                std::pair<long, long> sum = std::make_pair(candidate, complement);
                sums.insert(it, sum);
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }

    return sums;
}

int
main ()
{
    std::list<std::pair<long, long>> sums;
    std::list<std::pair<long, long>>::iterator it;

    for(long i = 4; i < 100; i+=2)
    {
        std::cout << "### " << i << " ###" << "\n";
        sums = goldbach(i);

        for (it = sums.begin(); it != sums.end(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it->first  << " + "  << it->second << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks much better. It seems you are only inserting at the end, consider using a vector instead, no need for an iterator there. Also, [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) `for(auto &v : sums) { v.first; v.second; }`